Register Form - Input data fetches 'Null' values from frontend to database (Express/PostgreSQL)
I am trying to get the user's information with a registration form from the frontend and save it to the database. However, each user entry results as a complete Null object in the terminal and a null row in the database;
Terminal:
{"customer_id":6,"first_name":null,"last_name":null,"e_mail":null,"password":null,"password2":null,"is_verified":false}
The user is already registered
{"customer_id":7,"first_name":null,"last_name":null,"e_mail":null,"password":null,"password2":null,"is_verified":false}
The user is already registered
PostgreSQL: (Table Name: customers)
Database Record
What should I change or add to my code to get the correct input? Any help is highly appreciated
**server.js
**
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const helmet = require('helmet')
const path = require('path');
const db = require('./public/models')
var engines = require('consolidate');
const userRoutes = require ('./public/routes/userRoutes')
const { Pool} = require('pg');

 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
const app = express()

const client = new Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  })

//middleware
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(helmet())
app.set('views', __dirname);
app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"../public")));


//Routes

  app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render("index");
  });
  app.get('/mainpage',(req,res)=>{
    res.render(__dirname + '/views/mainpage');
  });
  app.get('/mainpage/productdetails',(req,res)=>{
    res.render(__dirname + '/views/details');
  });
  app.get('/aboutus',(req,res)=>{
    res.render(__dirname + '/views/aboutus');
  });
  app.get('/dashboard',(req,res)=>{
    res.render(__dirname + '/views/myprofile', {user: newUser});
  });
  app.get('/payment',(req,res)=>{
    res.render(__dirname + '/views/payment', {user: newUser});
  });
  app.get('/register',(req,res)=>{
    res.render(__dirname + '/views/register.html');
  });
  app.get('/ordersummary',(req,res)=>{
    res.render(__dirname + '/views/summary', {user: newUser});
  });
  app.get('/login',(req,res)=>{
    res.render(__dirname + '/views/login.html');
  });
  
  app.post('/register', async (req,res) =>{
      
    var newUser = await pool.query(   
      `INSERT INTO customers(first_name,last_name,e_mail,password,password2) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING *`,  
      [req.body.firstname,req.body.lastname,req.body.email,req.body.password,req.body.password2])
      console.log(JSON.stringify(newUser.rows[0]));
    
      if(newUser.email !== undefined){
        console.log(req.body.email)
      }else{
        console.log('The user is already registered');
      }  
    });
  
    app.post('/login', async (req,res) => {  
      if(newUser.email !== undefined){  
        console.log(req.body.email) 
      }else{
        console.log('The user is already registered');
      }
    });

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is connected on ${PORT}`))

**register.html
**
    <form class="registerform"  id="register-form" action="/register" method="POST">    
    
        <h1> Sign Up </h1>
    
        <section> 
            <h2> Personal Information </h2>
            <p>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="firstname" class="col-2 col-form-label"> First Name: </label>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="lastname"  class="col-2 col-form-label"> Last Name: </label>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="email" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Email: </label>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="password" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Password: </label>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="password2" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Password: </label>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password2" placeholder="Re-Enter Your Password" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            </p>
        </section>
        <section> 
            <h2> Address Information </h2>
            <p>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="Address" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Address: </label>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="1234 Main St">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="address2" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Address 2: </label>
                <div class="col-10">    
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address2" placeholder="District and Apartment No">
                </div>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group row">       
                <label for="city" class="col-2 col-form-label"> City: </label>
                <div class="col-10">       
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city"> 
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group row"> 
                <label for="country" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Country: </label>
                <div class="col-10"> 
                <select id="country" class="form-control" style="font-size: 1rem;">
                    <option selected>Choose from the list</option>          
                    <option>United States</option>           
                    <option>United Kingdom</option>            
                    <option>Germany</option>           
                    <option>France</option>           
                    <option>Japan</option>            
                    <option>Canada</option>           
                    <option>Spain</option>            
                    <option>South Korea</option>            
                    <option>China</option>            
                    <option>Russia</option>           
                    <option>Belarus</option>            
                    <option>Turkey</option>          
                    <option>India</option>
                    <option>Italy</option>
                    <option>UAE</option>      
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            &nbsp;
            <div class="form-group row">      
                <label for="postcode" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Postcode: </label>
                <div class="col-10"> 
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postcode">
                </div>
            </div>
            </p>
            <div class="button1">
                <input type="submit" value="Register" id="submitButton">
            </div> 
            <a style="font-weight:bold;padding-left:3em;padding-bottom: 5em;" href="/login">Already registered? Sign In here</a>
        </section>
        </form>
        <script>
            const formRegister = document.querySelector('registerform');
    
            formRegister.addEventListener('submit',event =>{
                event.preventDefault();
    
                const formData = new FormData(formRegister);
                const data = new URLSearchParams(formData);
    
                fetch('http://localhost:4000/register', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: data
                }). then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => console.log(data))
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
            });
        </script>

**users.js
**

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const newUser = sequelize.define( "customers", {
        first_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        last_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        e_mail: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
            isEmail: true, //checks for email format
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        password2: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        is_verified: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue: false
          },

    }, {timestamps: false}, )

    return newUser
}


In register.html if you are selecting form by class then it should be document.querySelector('.registerform');  not the one that is present in your script.

Also, one cause I can think of is mismatched column names or casing issues, the form has last name and the model has last_name.

I made both of the changes but I continue to run into the same problem.

//Try this I have fixed it.
<form class="registerform"  id="register-form" action="/register" method="POST">
    <h1> Sign Up </h1>
    <section>
        <h2> Personal Information </h2>
        <p>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="firstname" class="col-2 col-form-label"> First Name: </label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="lastname"  class="col-2 col-form-label"> Last Name: </label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="email" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Email: </label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="password" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Password: </label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="password2" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Password: </label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Re-Enter Your Password" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        </p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2> Address Information </h2>
        <p>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="Address" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Address: </label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="1234 Main St">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="address2" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Address 2: </label>
            <div class="col-10">    
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address2" name="address2" placeholder="District and Apartment No">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="city" class="col-2 col-form-label"> City: </label>
            <div class="col-10">       
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city"> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="country" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Country: </label>
            <div class="col-10">
                <select id="country" name="country" class="form-control" style="font-size: 1rem;">
                    <option selected>Choose from the list</option>
                    <option>United States</option>
                    <option>United Kingdom</option>
                    <option>Germany</option>
                    <option>France</option>
                    <option>Japan</option>
                    <option>Canada</option>
                    <option>Spain</option>
                    <option>South Korea</option>
                    <option>China</option>
                    <option>Russia</option>
                    <option>Belarus</option>
                    <option>Turkey</option>
                    <option>India</option>
                    <option>Italy</option>
                    <option>UAE</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        &nbsp;
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="postcode" class="col-2 col-form-label"> Postcode: </label>
            <div class="col-10"> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postcode" name="postcode">
            </div>
        </div>
        </p>
        <div class="button1">
            <input type="submit" value="Register" id="submitButton">
        </div>
        <a style="font-weight:bold;padding-left:3em;padding-bottom: 5em;" href="/login">Already registered? Sign In here</a>
    </section>
</form>
<script>
    const formRegister = document.querySelector('.registerform');
    
    formRegister.addEventListener('submit',event =>{
        event.preventDefault();

        const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(event.target).entries());
        console.log(data);

        fetch('http://localhost:4000/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
        }). then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    });
</script>

